# How do I list the values being counted?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use the aggregate function to count the most occurring unique values (which lets say is 5). I now want to list these unique values that were counted in a column - struggling with how to do that. Can I even do that?  I'm using PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT IDs, 
COUNT(DISTINCT people) AS num_people
FROM class

GROUP BY IDs
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT people) desc
LIMIT 1
```

Current Sample Result:

```
 -------------------------------------
|   **IDs**   |     **num_people**    |
 -------------------------------------
| Aabbcc      |        5              |
 -------------------------------------
```

I want this result with the new column at thee end. (It could be a separate rows too - it
does not have to be all in one row - but that would be ideal)

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    **IDs**  |     **num_people**    |        **people_listed**        |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Aabbcc      |    5                  | Coco, Riley, Allan, Betty, Cici | 
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: provide some sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: Added expected output and current result. Also simplified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the aggregate function `ARRAY_AGG` or `STRING_AGG` for that:

```
SELECT IDs, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT people) AS num_people,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT people, ', ') AS people_listed
FROM class
GROUP BY IDs
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT people) desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for clemens! Thank you!